# Why shortcutting euler circuit creates a hamilton circuit in Christofides algorithm

Tags: algorithms, traveling-salesman

In step 6 of the [Christofides algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm) it is implicitly suggested that there is an invarient that the euler circuit can always be shortcutted to an hamilton circuit, what exactly assures us that? e.g (let u,v,w be vertices in the graph.) in the euler circuit, if vertex v has already been visited once, and is being revisited after visiting u and right before visiting w what makes the shortcut edge u-w to always exist?

Comment: It's assumed that the graph $G$ is complete, so the edge $(u, v)$ exists by definition. Look at the example on the Wiki page you referred to

Comment: right, missed that in the TSP problem definition. thanks!